# Missing Site Columns in NewForm, EditForm, DispForm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, migration

I did a list migration on list with zero customization using a third party tool (Metalogix: Content Matrix).

After migrating the list, I went to create a new list item, I noticed I was missing site columns; so I proceeded to check list settings to confirm whether they were there.

I found that the site columns were still on the site columns list for the list. I then checked the edit and display forms to find the same site columns were missing.

So I tried creating a new "NewForm" and it was still missing the site columns I needed.

Does anyone know of a way I could get the site columns back I need?

Comment: Did the missing columns have any validation, or look ups?  If so, you might just have to recreate them.

Comment: what type of column it is?  it is very much hard to trouble shoot the 3rd party tools...I think it is best if you post the question on metalogix forum or directly contact with vendor..

Comment: I ended up creating a custom content type for each list and just remapped the data to the correct fields. That seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the content type/s associated with the list.  If no content types are shown in the list settings temporarily enable them in the advanced settings.  In the content type settings check the columns haven't been removed from the content type and also check they are not hidden.  If the site columns have been removed from the content type then you can add them back and you should find existing metadata will be retained for items already in the list.

If the content types are ok then it could be the ShowOnEdit etc settings for the columns.  These settings are not visible via the front end but a free tool like SharePoint Manager (available via the Codeplex site https://spm.codeplex.com/) allows you to see and change them.  Alternatively you could run PowerShell commands to see what they are set to if your happy with using PowerShell.